# Apple Official Demo tableview insert row issue

Tags: ios, animation, tableview

I was learning the official demo iPhoneCoreDataRecipes and I found a problem.

The scenario is like this:

There is a tableview displaying some line of data. When the edit button is clicked, an additional line appears and it has some text like: add a new xxx. When click on that line, you can make a new line of data to the tableview.

When the edit button is clicked again, that line disappears and the tableview is in display mode.

Each line also has a `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` style when editing except the add new line line.

The problem is that when switching between edit and display mode, the additional "add" line appears and disappears and its animation influences the animation of the line just above it(The last real line).

Has anyone come across this problem and does anyone know how to solve it?

[image]

When switching between the edit and display mode, the line Add Ingredient appears and disappears.
The animation of the line above it, the Sugar line, is affected and is different to the lines above it.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am using this, just in the recipedetail view. I will get a screenshot.

Comment: The screenshot is udapted

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't really show anything. But is the issue that the delete button animates in from a different position for the last ingredient, and also some flickering in the cell separator for the last ingredient's cell?

Comment: what is the pure issue here...? how did you mean _its animation influences the animation of the line just above it_ exactly?

Comment: I added one more screenshot, can you see the difference? The Warm Water was about to turn to edit mode, and its transition animation is different to the cells above it. It is affected by the add ingredient line, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is improved if, in `setEditing:animated:` in `RecipeDetailViewController.m`, you move this line:

```
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
```

inside the bracketing calls to

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
```

and

```
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```